# Knockout Bootstrap modal nightmare

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, modal-dialog

I have a Twitter Bootstrap application using Bootstrap modal windows.  The page is built with knockout js.  The page is a SPA with 10 rows.  Each row has it's own hidden modal window which appears when the user clicks a button.  However the modal box has a textbox which can't be edited for some reason.  The same happens on all browsers.

Each modal contains a form element.

```
<!-- ko foreach: talks -->
<div data-bind="showModal: $data.ShowModal" class="modal fade">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" 
        action="#" 
        data-bind="submit: $root.createTalk, attr: { 'id': $data.ModalId }" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Add Talk</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
<div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" >Title:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input name="title" data-bind="value: $data.Title, attr: { 'id': $data.TitleIdStr() }" type="text" />
```

Each input box has a unique id and the form is unique.  I really can't see why this keeps happening.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is your containerless binding nested within another element?

Comment: What does the ShowModal method look like?

Comment: Would need a bit more info to properly debug this.  Small hint, in loops you don't have to use $data to get properties, can just use the property itself.  e.g. `value: Title`

Comment: Perhaps this would help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background?rq=1