# Sidebar with bootstrap modal do not update

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to ruby on rails, I have been recommended to using a sidebar so that on most pages it will show what I want. I currently have an application on its own page called Todo List. It simply let you create a task and displays the tasks. It runs on its own page. Now I want to move that app and let it function in my sidebar. I have implemented my sidebar as follow.

```
/views/layouts/application (in body)
<%= yield :sidebar %>

/views/myapp1/index
<% content_for(:sidebar) do %>
 <% render :partial => "layouts/sidebar" %>
<% end %>


/views/layouts/_sidebar
 <% if logged_in? %>
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">

  <div class="row", id="container_todo_lists">
   <%= render @todo_lists %>
  </div>

  <div class="links" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mynewtodo_list">
   <%= link_to('New Todo List', 'javascript:;', :id => :random) %>
  </div>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
 </div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">☰ Todo List</span>
<script>
 function openNav() {document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";}

 function closeNav() {document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";}
</script>

<% end %> 

<!-- Modal  create action -->
  <%= form_for(@todo_list, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="modal fade" id="mynewtodo_list" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Todo</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :title %><br>
            <%= f.text_area :title, class: "form-control todo_list_title" %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :description %><br>
            <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control todo_list_content" %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <%= submit_tag "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="mynewtodo_listclose">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<!-- Modal -->


/views/todo_lists/_todo_list.html.erb
<div class="text-center" id="todo_list_<%= todo_list.id %>">

                <h3 class="panel-title"><%= todo_list.title %>
                  <sup style="color: #3BB2D6; position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 15px; text-align:right;">
                      (<%= time_ago_in_words(todo_list.created_at) %>)
                  </sup>
                </h3>

                <p><%= todo_list.description %></p>

                <div class="row" role="group">
                    <div class="links1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myupdatetodo_list_<%= todo_list.id %>">
                      <%= link_to('Edit', 'javascript:;', :id => :random) %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="links1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myitemtodo_list_<%= todo_list.id %>">
                      <%= link_to('Show', 'javascript:;', :id => :random) %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="links1">
                      <%= link_to 'Destroy', todo_list, method: :delete, remote: true %>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

```
        <!-- Modal - update posts -->
              <%= form_for(todo_list, :method => :put, remote: true) do |f| %>
              <div class="modal fade" id="myupdatetodo_list_<%= todo_list.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">

                  <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :title %><br>
                    <%= f.text_area :title, class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :description %><br>
                    <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="myupdatebutton_<%= todo_list.id %>" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <%= submit_tag "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <% end %>
        <!-- Modal -->

        <!-- Modal - item posts -->
              <%= form_for(todo_list, :method => :put, remote: true) do |f| %>
              <div class="modal fade" id="myitemtodo_list_<%= todo_list.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Items</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">



                  <h3><%= todo_list.title %></h3>
                  <p><%= todo_list.description %></p>



                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="myitembutton_<%= todo_list.id %>" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <%= submit_tag "Add Item", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <% end %>
        <!-- Modal -->
```

I had a gray screen problem where my modal is in a div narbar class and that cause the screen to only display the backgroup screen. So I found a solution on

[Bootstrap 3 - modal disappearing below backdrop when using a fixed sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126617/bootstrap-3-modal-disappearing-below-backdrop-when-using-a-fixed-sidebar/21127348#21127348)

so I added the script to the views/layouts/

```
 var checkeventcount = 1,prevTarget;
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    if(typeof prevTarget == 'undefined' || (checkeventcount==1 && e.target!=prevTarget))
    {  
      prevTarget = e.target;
      checkeventcount++;
      e.preventDefault();
      $(e.target).appendTo('body').modal('show');
    }
    else if(e.target==prevTarget && checkeventcount==2)
    {
      checkeventcount--;
    }
 });
```

So now the screen pops out and I can view the tasks. However, I cannot update the tasks. I tried 4 hours working around the problem and I think what happens now is that the update modal is not catching my update.js.erb file so it cannot edit the todo list. I think it has to do with being added to the "body" and somehow it is not making the connection to the js file in the todo list folder. I think I have to alter the script above somehow but not sure what. Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle with your code??

Comment: Does jfiddle work with ruby on rails?, my todo list controllers are ruby on rails. From what I know jfiddle only work with the settings. My function works fine on its own page. But the problem is my navbar after adding the extra modal script I cannot update the todo_list. I can try to add jfiddle but not sure how that will help

Comment: kk. Then can u show me a working model of your code..!!