# Backone events off of Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, coffeescript

So I recently had to make a change to CSS that made a view that holds a backbone Modal `position: fixed;`. This of course caused the problem of the modal appearing behind the backdrop as this SO [outlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background#_=_).

Now I can't necessarily change the CSS without messing up the app, so I opted to go the route of when the user clicks the modal button to append the modal to the body:

```
 events:
        "click .share": "adjustModal"

    adjustModal: ->
        $('#shareAccessModal').appendTo("body")
```

This works great. However, I now seem to no longer be hitting events triggered from the modal.

Previously this worked great:

```
events:
            "keyup [type='text']#sharedAccess": "updateEmail"

updateEmail: (e) ->
            if e.keyCode == 13 && e.currentTarget.value != ""
                $('p').remove()
                if @model.get('email')
                    @email = @model.get('email')    + "|" + e.currentTarget.value
                else
                    @email = e.currentTarget.value
                array = @email.split("|")
                for email, i in array 
                    $('.emails').append('<p>' + email + ' <button type="button" class="close" ><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button></p>')

                e.currentTarget.value = ""
```

But now updateEmail never seems to be getting called.

Here's my template:

```
<div class="container">
    <a id="back" href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
    </a>
    <div class="message"><%= @title %></div>
    <div class="btn btn-inline pull-right continue">Continue</div>
    <div class="btn btn-inline pull-right share" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#shareAccessModal"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Share Access</div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="shareAccessModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Grant Access</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" id="sharedAccess" class="shared-access" placeholder="Enter email addresses of users allowed to edit/view">
        <div class="emails">
            <h3>Users with access:</h3>
            <% for email, i in @email.split("|"): %>
                <p><%= email %> <button type="button" class="close" ><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button></p>
            <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how I should change my code so that I can still act on events triggered from the view? Namely pressing enter in the text field.

Comment: Any reason that you're trying to reuse `#shareAccessModal` rather than creating and destroying it as needed? Re-using views often destroys events because `x.html(y)` destroys events to avoid memory leaks. I recommend creating brand new views when you need them and destroying them when you don't, that avoids all kinds of problems.

Comment: The modal has to be within the view's el for the events to be caught by the Backbone-View. Is it within the view's el ?