# bootstrap modal backdrop cover modal

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem with Modal in my PHP pages.

This is my page code [(DEMO)](http://jsfiddle.net/x468un4h/1/) but in my pages I see the Backdrop that cover the modal like in the image [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKSzl.png).

I include in my pages nprogress tool but I tried to remove it, but I have the same problem.

I call the modal function into an IF in my PHP like this:

```
<?php
if($verificaMail=='n'){
?>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#myModal').modal()
        });
    </script>
<?php           
}
?>
```

And I put the modal code at the bottom of the page, before the `</body>` tag like this:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap modal appearing under background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background)

Comment: I read the other post but is not my case. I have my modal just before the `</body>` tag and no position property in css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using this code:

```
#myModal .modal-dialog{
    z-index: 1041 !important;
}
```

But if I would that when a user click outside from the modal, it doesn't close? What I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css.

```
#myModal {
  z-index: 16777271 !important;
}
```

or call `$("#myModal").css("z-index", "1500");` after opening.

`z-index` gives the priority to the div, how higher the number how higher the priority.

Comment: I tried your solution but without success :( The strange thing is that in JSFiddle it runs without problem...is the same code of my page...