# How to open bootstrap modal in react component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap4-modal

Have a react component. Need to open bootstrap modal on page load. Tried using jQuery and simple javascript but with no success.

React Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import $ from 'jquery'

class Login extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // here I want to open modal
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="modal fade WelcomeModal" id="WelcomeModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <div className="camera-box">
                <img alt="" src="/img/yellow-logo.svg"/>
                <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Welcome to the Cozy App!</h5>
              </div>                             
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              <p className="text-center">On the following screens weʼll ask you to register the Cozys in your home & adjust your temperature settings. Youʼll need the following information:</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need jquery. You can display the modal using properties in the state.

Comment: Could you please post an example!

Comment: use this https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241912/bootstrap-modal-in-react-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap modal in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241912/bootstrap-modal-in-react-js)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/jagzviruz/pen/pxPqbj) which shows how you can combine Bootstrap Classes with React without needing jQuery

```
toggleModal = () => this.setState({
              showLogin: !this.state.showLogin
          })
```

Comment: This is nice, but if you click on the modal itself it will dimiss

Answer (score 2):

first of all, DO NOT USE JQUERY IN REACT.
you just need to set an state for show or hide modal. that's it.

```
// In functional components:
<div onClick={setState(true)}
// In class components:
<div onClick={this.setState({showModal: true})}
```

Comment: Where to use that state var so that modal can toggle ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Jquery for this purpose, all you need to do is to play with bootstrap css classes, which in turn show or hide the modal.

You can see an example in the below link

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/n9zn3n43o0)

Comment: This does not provide the full bootstrap modal functionality. Bootstrap modals rely heavily on additional javascript, implementing focus trap, body scroll lock and backdrop rendering, to name just a few.

Comment: @zephi : if you need all the animations and other functionality do refer reactstrap [https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/] this provides most of the bootstrap components as react components.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that bootstrap modals aren't a css-only solution. Your claim that all you need to do is play with css classes may therefore be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Include the Js cdn in your public folder index.html
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Then call the bootstrap modal as regular, 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: Providing it in code format would've been better, But anyway good work keep it up.