# React modal is not getting shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, bootstrap-4, react-redux

I am new to the react js. Here, what I am doing is I have a modal that I want to show on click of a button.

```
   export class QuestionDetails extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal : false
    }
  }

questionAnalitic(analitics) {
    if (!(analitics.length <= 0) || (analitics == undefined)) {
      return analitics.map((analiticss) =>
        <div className="col-md-8 d-flex justify-content-around questionDetailRow1">
          <div>
            <span><i className="fa fa-check-circle" style={{ fontSize: '24px', color: '#0f9d8f' }}></i></span><span className="ml-2">{analiticss.correct}</span>

          </div>
          <div>
            <span> <i class="fa fa-times-circle" style={{ fontSize: '24px', color: 'rgb(251, 76, 47)' }}></i></span><span className="ml-2">{analiticss.wrong}</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span className='skip-background'><i className="fa fa-fast-forward" style={{ color: 'black' }}></i></span><span className="ml-2">{analiticss.skipped}</span>
          </div>
          {
            this.props.isInViewMode ?
              null
              :
              <button type="button" onClick={() => this.setState({showModal: true})} className="btn btn-outline-primary">Change</button>
          }
        </div>
      );
    }


render() {
    return (
      //  <span className="selectJdMsg alert alert-info">Please select the Question to See the more details</span>
      < div className="justify-content-between align-items-center" >
        <div className="row mt-2" style={{ alignItems: 'center' }} >
          <h5 className="col-md-4 " style={{ paddingLeft: '15px', fontSize: '18px', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Question {this.props.questionNo}</h5>
          {this.questionAnalitic(this.props.questionAnalitics)}
        </div>
         {  this.state.showModal && <ConfirmationModal /> }
</div>
</div>
</div>


confirmModal.js

import React from 'react';
const ConfirmationModal = () => {
  return (
    <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div className="modal-content">
          <div className="modal-header">
            <h6 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Change this Question?</h6>
            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-body">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-12 text-center ">
                <span className="">
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-primary modalBtnSize" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#changeQuestionModal" >Change by creating your own Question</button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-12 text-center marginForOrOption">
                <span>or</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
                <span className="">
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary modalBtnSize">Change and Replace from Question bank</button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-footer">
            {/* <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> */}

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default ConfirmationModal;
```

SO, here What I am doing is that , there is a change button on click of that button I am opening a modal by using the states.

so I have a state that is `showModal` which is by default false. now when I click on the button the state gets changed and it becomes true and there, that modal should get shown  from the line ,

```
{ this.state.showModal && <confirmModal />  }
```

So Here what happens is that when  i used console log in the confirm modal then also it shows the console log value but the modal does not get shown.

Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: You might find it is getting rendered,  React does not show / hide controls it renders them.  Looks like your using bootsrap, in this case Modals are rendereded hidden, and it's `modal()` method that shows them.

Comment: yes I am using bootstrap 4

Comment: Here I see that in the html structure there is a modal structure

Comment: But that modal is not getting shown

Comment: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

Comment: I dont want to use the react-bootstrap . I just want to use the bootstrap4

Comment: You will then need to fire the modal manually, call it's `.modal("show")` method, a good place here would be to make `ConfirmationModal` into a class, and call it on CompoenntDidMount.

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33063095/171456

Comment: Hey I used the ReactStrap Now I am able to see the modal but Here value property in the react form used in that modal header is not getting filled . But in the props I am getting that value. So, I am not able to understand why it is not filled.