# Modal not showing correctly when i put it into a Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular-strap

I can't reproduce the [AngularStrap's example](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/modals),  here a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/guRJKbXk6qDfTcZjcQqB?p=preview)

### What I get when I integrate this example in my code:

[image]
(As you can see it's a bit darker, i don't know why...)

### What I'm expecting:

[image]

Actually I spent a whole day looking for solution for this but no luck.

guest.html

```
<body ng-app="module.app">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse  navbar-static-top">
            <div topbar></div>
        </nav>  

        <div class="row">
             <div ui-view></div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
```

topBar directive.js :

```
topBarModule.directive('topbar', function() {

    return {
          restrict: 'EAC',
          templateUrl: 'app/shared/topBar/topBar.html',
          controller: 'TopBarController'
          //ad controller for more controll logged user etc....
    };
});
```

topBar.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    ...
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-animation="am-fade-and-scale" data-placement="center" bs-modal="modal">Click to toggle modal
                              <br>
      <small>(using an object)</small>
      </button>

   </div>
   ...
</div>
```

topBarController.js:

```
var topBarModule = angular.module('module.topBar', ['ui.router','mgcrea.ngStrap','ngAnimate','ngSanitize']);

topBarModule.controller('TopBarController', function($cookieStore,$scope,Session,Department,Auth,$window,$modal,$rootScope) {

    //..
    $rootScope.modal = {title: 'Title', content: 'Hello Modal<br />This is a multiline message!'};

});
```

I can't see where's the problem, can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: have you tried increasing z-index of modal?

Comment: I don't know what z-index means, but i'll try it, thanks for suggestion!

Comment: i'm into this now, this is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, using @dhaval suggestion

The problem is - [As mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11788713/1154692) - that the parent element have a fixed or relative position this behavior will occur..

So just deleted the `navbar-static-top` attribute and it's work now:

```
<body ng-app="module.app">
    <div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse  navbar-static-top"> -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div topbar></div>
        </nav>  

        <div class="row">
             <div ui-view></div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
```