# NgStrap's Aside not showing correctly

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This is a bit similar to [my previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29691034/modal-not-showing-correctly-when-i-put-it-into-a-directive) but now i'm working with [Aside](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/asides)

My problem is the following :
[image]

It's not showing correctly.. Here a working [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/5QksJ2DGBfwVP0fZcqyT?p=preview), but when I try to do exactly the same in my project, it don't get the same result.

Here my code structure:

**index.html** where all ui-router views are injected here:

```
<body ng-app="module.app">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                  <div topbar></div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div sideBar></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-10">

                        <div ui-view="messageBoard"> </div>
                        <div ui-view="ticketView"> </div>

                        <div ui-view> </div>

                    </div>

        </div>

</body>
```

An empty controller for now, but it should work:

```
var chatModule = angular.module('module.chat', ['ui.router','angularMoment','mgcrea.ngStrap.aside']);

chatModule.controller('ChatController', function($scope, $aside,$rootScope) {
});
```

**Route**  as you can see **This state will be injected in the unamed view of the main HTML file**:

```
chatModule.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
                .state('Chat', {
                                      url: '/Chat',
                                      templateUrl: 'app/shared/chat/views/chat.html',
                                      controller: 'ChatController',

                                })


});
```

**chatbox.html**

```
<div>
<b>this is a template</b>

</div>
```

**chat.html**(copy paste from ngStrap's doc)

```
<button  type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-template="app/shared/chat/views/chatbox.html" data-placement="left" data-animation="am-slide-left" bs-aside="aside" data-container="body">Custom aside
  <br>
  <small>(using data-template)</small>
</button>
```

Any suggestion to make this solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you include the css as well?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/styles/libs.min.css">
```

Comment: ohh thanks, the doc need to be more clear about dependencies, the modal for example don't need css include..