# Hidden modal not rendering on button click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, modal-dialog

Here is my `HTML`:

```
  <div class='row sheet-row'>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>Fruits</div>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <button class='btn btn-primary' data-target='signup-52' data-toggle='modal'>Sign up</button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-3'></div>
  </div>
  <div aria-hidden='true' aria-labelledby='Sign up' class='modal hide fade' id='signup-52' role='dialog' tabindex='-1'>
    <div class='modal-header'>
      <button aria-hidden='true' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' type='button'>×</button>
      <h3 id='myModalLabel'>Sign up</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-body'>
      <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-footer'>
      <button aria-hidden='true' class='btn' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
      <button class='btn btn-primary'>Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The button `data-target` matches the modal `id` yet when I click the button, nothing happens.

Any suggestions for troubleshooting would be appreciated.  I have never implemented a modal, so it is likely a pretty basic oversight.  I even tried changing `aria-hidden` to `false` in the modal to see if it would appear on initial page render, but it did not.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to `@Guruprasad Rao` (answer below), I now have a working `Fiddle`, but still not working code:

1. View is in `HAML` - renders in `HTML`.  On button click, nothing happens.
2. I View Source, copy `HTML` for one button and one modal into `Fiddle`.
3. `Fiddle` works perfectly with the same code which is not working on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing `//= require bootstrap` in `application.js`.  Still not sure why all of my other Bootstrap styling worked without it but it was needed for modals.  Once I did that, I had the "modal is in the background" problem but solved that with this great answer [Bootstrap modal appearing under background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background/26651375#26651375).

Answer (score 1):

It should be `data-target='#signup-52'` and remove `hide` class from `modal` and keep only `modal fade`

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y9ezxq11/)**

Comment: Thanks.  I made these changes but no love.  I click and nothing happens.  I even loaded my new HTML in your fiddle and it works fine there, just not on my page.  Is there some Rails or other environment setting which could be blocking?

Comment: I should mention I have multiple buttons on my page (with a modal for each).  Each has a unique `data-target`/`id` so it should work (in theory).

Comment: OK since I am not using jQuery for this, I configure the Fiddle for pure JS.  I also selected "No wrap - in body" since my `modal` code follows my `button` code.  The Fiddle still works fine but my code doesn't.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Rao I did and there aren't any.  I just updated my `bootstrap-rails` gem to version 3.3.3 and it is still not working.  Anything else needed for modals to work?

Comment: No nothing. That should actually do.. But as a 1 last suggestion I can tell is just just copy and paste a demo code of bootstrap modal in your project as a dummy model and try to open it..