# Bootstrap modal - screen goes black

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have two modals, they pop up on button click. One works fine, however for the second one, the screen just goes black and nothing happens:

First, working modal:

```
<div id="deleteConfirmation" class="hidden, modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h5>Are you sure you want to delete this contact?</h5>
      <button id="deleteOk">
        Yes
      </button>
      <button id="deleteNo">
        No
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and pops up on this command:

```
$('#deleteConfirmation').modal('show');
```

Second one, is almost identical, but not working:

```
<div id="addContact" class="hidden, modal fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5>Add New Contact</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content"> 
      <label>First Name </label><input /> <br />
      <label>Last Name </label><input /> <br />
      <label>Address </label><input /> <br />
      <label>Phone Number </label><input /> <br />

      <button id="addConfirm">
        Confirm
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the command:

```
$('#addContact').modal('show');
```

It's basically two identical modals, however for the second one, screen just goes black, and the first modal works correctly. I assume it's one of the classes that I'm using. What seems to be off here?

Comment: Make use of class instead of id, when your creating same stuff multiple times.

Comment: @stanze He **is** using it correctly. What's the problem there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created some modals at bootply and adapted your code, check out if this is of any help.

[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/tNBPwl5SwL)

Comment: The link in this answer no longer works so no idea what the solution was. This similar issue with a still current answer may be a clue to whomever comes here later: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background . In my case it was due to the faulty modal being inside a fixed-position parent, causing the background to be added on top of it.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo here:

```
<div id="deleteConfirmation" class="hidden, modal fade">
<div id="addContact" class="hidden, modal fade">
```

Remove the commas:

```
<div id="deleteConfirmation" class="hidden modal fade">
<div id="addContact" class="hidden modal fade">
```

So the script is unable to determine whether the `hidden` class is correctly applied or not, and ultimately you won't see anything other than a **black** screen of death! `:O`

Comment: I tried that as well, but produces the same results.

Comment: @Mefhisto1 Do you have any other scripts or CSS that modifies them? Okay, do one thing. Right click on the black screen and inspect the modal window.

Comment: @Mefhisto1 Do you have a working demo anywhere hosted?

Answer (score 1):

I think the real thing to do here is to remove the hidden class in your div tags by changing this:

```
<div id="deleteConfirmation" class="hidden modal fade">
<div id="addContact" class="hidden modal fade">
```

to this

```
<div id="deleteConfirmation" class="modal fade">
<div id="addContact" class="modal fade">
```

if you go through the bootstrap doc you wont see where a hidden class was added: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this to fix.

`$("#deleteConfirmation").prependTo("body");`

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. $("#deleteConfirmation").prependTo("body");

Answer (score 0):

May Be your bootstrap model inside any div try to put the end of the body :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).