# bootstrap dialog get closed on click on area inside it

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use [bootstrap material](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html) and my problem is that dialog get colsed immediately after I click inside it. I'd like to be able to close it but only on close button or clicking outside. But not indiside!

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <section id="landing">
        <button id="video-button" class="btn btn-success btn-raised" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#video-dialog">
            Quick tour
        </button>
    </section>
    <section id="about">
    </section>

    <!-- video dialog -->
    <div id="video-dialog" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Dialog</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>body. when I click here the dialog get closed.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Dismiss</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

The problem is in **div.modal-backdrop** because it's before the modal's content and actually covers my dialog.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle link so we can help you properly?

Comment: here is working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ryt5bh3e/2/ be my guest

Comment: in provided jsfiddle, mine does **not** close when you click inside of the `body`, 'x' and 'dismiss' work as expected.

Comment: What browser do you use, @VladRia?

Comment: In any browser. Thanks for JSFiddle! Anyway I added details to my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background