# Can't click anything after i open my Bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

sorry for the basic question, I'm working on MVC ASP.NET and I'm trying to add a bootstrap modal in my navbar, I run the code, i can see the button i can touch on it, but after it open, the screen is unclickable i have to f5 to click anywhere again, it's the first time i use modals from bootstrap, and search all around google if I have to write some JavaScript code, but everywhere says that you just need jquery , bootstrap.js and .css and nothing else. If I'm missing something just let me know. Thanks, Here is my code.

PD: I have a carousel already working from bootstrap

```
@if (Session["usuario"] == null)
            {
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                    Ingresar
                </button>

                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Iniciar Sesión</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("DoLogin","Usuario")">
                                        <span class="alert-danger">@ViewBag.NoUser</span>
                                        <label for="NombreDeUsuario" class="sr-only">Nombre de Usuario</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="NombreDeUsuario" name="NombreDeUsuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa tu Usuario" required="" autofocus="" />
                                        <br />

                                        <label for="Contrasena" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label>
                                        <input type="password" id="Contrasena" name="Contrasena" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa tu Contraseña" required="" />
                                        <br />
                                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Ingresar</button>
                                 </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem 
[image]

Comment: you mean, when modal open, you can not click anywhere on modal screen? or outside modal screen?

Comment: anywhere, i try to touch inside the modal, outside the modal but its like the page get blocked, i will aploud a screenshot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background i just find the solution right there

Answer (score 37):

```
.modal-backdrop {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: my answer is for the specific question above (-_-)

Comment: Your solution works like a charm but it would be really helpful to understand why the Bootstrap guys still use `z-index: 1040;` in 2020 while it's seems to be simply wrong for quite a bunch of people.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).off('focusin.modal');
```

Its just because the modal is focused.

Answer (score 0):

How it got fixed in my case.

The problem was after copying the modal and making some changes I had put all the contents inside the dialog part and removed the modal content and body. So to enable clicks on elements add your main contents to the modal content part or preferably in the body section. This will fix it.