# bootstrap modal doesn't work properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've created a navigation bar and in this navigation bar I have login in option . I want a login in window pops out once I hit on it . So I created a modal bootstrap and the thing is it works but once it comes out the whole screen dims rather than the every thing but the pop up modal . Any idea where am I making my mistake ?

```
  <header id="mu-header">  
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default mu-main-navbar" role="navigation">  
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <!-- FOR MOBILE VIEW COLLAPSED BUTTON -->
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <!-- LOGO -->                                                        
          <!--  Image based logo  -->
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Logo img"></a> 
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right mu-main-nav">
            <li><a href="#mu-reservation">Order Here</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#mu-restaurant-menu">MENU</a></li>   
            <li><a href="#mu-gallery">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#mu-contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#mu-slider">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#mu-about-us">ABOUT US</a></li>                  
            <li><a class="login" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</a></li>
          </ul>                            
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->       
      </div>          




    </nav> 


    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>This is a large modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: "Dims"? Doesn't the Bootstrap modal automatically dim the page behind it?

Comment: that's how it should be but for me even the modal is dimmed and freezed @Crowes I've added the image for the better understanding of my situation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap modal appearing under background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background)

Comment: @Crowes Thanks man useful link ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes bootstrap modal does that when it is inside an element that has: `position: relative;` or `position:fixed;` See if that is your case.