# Bootstrap modal not working with timer

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Im trying to load a modal after a 3 second page load delay
The code below opens the modal however i cannot close it and the grey overlay is on top of the content etc

Code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function() {
$('#myModal').modal();
}, 3000);
});
</script>
            <!-- Modal HTML -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Join IQ Option Today</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body text-center">
                        <a target="_blank" href="mylink"><img src="myimage.jpg" width="300" height="600" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: See that your modal is not nested under any other elements... If it is, try to put it just before the body closing tag

Comment: makes no difference at all
still faded background overlaying entire image & screen & still unable to close

Comment: I have also tried the solution involving removing the position: style as well as outlined here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background?rq=1

but still no difference

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

My ***css*** contained `z-index:1`

I've commented that out and it now works perfectly!