# Bootstrap modal not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iphone

This is the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalInsertAgression" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalInsertAgression" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="card">

        <form id="formInsertarAgresion" action="{% url 'insertarAgresion' %}" role="form">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="card-header card-header-icon" data-background-color="rose">
                <i class="material-icons">place</i>
            </div>

            <div class="card-content">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test</h4>
                <p class="text-center" id="msgModalInsertAgression"></p>
                <br>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="material-icons">date_range</i></span>
                    <div class="form-group">{{ agresionForm.fecha }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card-footer pull-right">
                <button id="btnInsertModalInsertAgression" type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-rose">Insertar</button>
                <button id="btnCloseModalInsertAgression" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-fill" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

I open it with:

```
$("#modalInsertAgression").show();
```

It does not work on iPhone, when the modal appears the background keeps black and it lost the focus, you can not click in the modal or the buttons.

**Edit: The modal only works with `$("#modalInsertAgression").modal({backdrop: false});` but I do not want to lose the black background...**

Answer (score 0):

Try with (tested on **iOS 11**):

```
$('#modalInsertAgression').modal('show');
```

Snippet:

```js
$('#modalInsertAgression').modal('show');
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="modalInsertAgression" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalInsertAgression" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="card">
      <form id="formInsertarAgresion" action="{% url 'insertarAgresion' %}" role="form">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="card-header card-header-icon" data-background-color="rose">
          <i class="material-icons">place</i>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h4 class="card-title">Test</h4>
          <p class="text-center" id="msgModalInsertAgression"></p>
          <br>
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="material-icons">date_range</i></span>
            <div class="form-group">{{ agresionForm.fecha }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer pull-right">
          <button id="btnInsertModalInsertAgression" type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-rose">Insertar</button>
          <button id="btnCloseModalInsertAgression" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-fill" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It does not work for me on iPhone 6 iOS 11.2.6
Only works with `$("#modalInsertAgression").modal({backdrop: false});` but it loses the black background...

Comment: Which bootstrap version is it? Are you able to create a working fiddle at least for desktop, because it wasn't the case with the shared code. By the way, with the backdrop approach you are removing indeed the black background.

Comment: It is bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: Jota, in that case you have a working example above with the code fragment you've shared, if you still can't fix it, maybe share more code or a url?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:

> If the modal container has a fixed or relative position or is within
>   an element with fixed or relative position this behavior will occur.
>   [Bootstrap modal appearing under background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and discovered the class "table-responsive" applied to parent element was blocking the modal to work properly on iPhones.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Title</td>
<td>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
 <button     type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">  Launch demo modal</button>.   
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">  <div class="modal-dialog">    <div class="modal-content">      <div class="modal-header">        
<h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>        
<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>      </div>      
<div class="modal-body">        ...      </div>      
 <div class="modal-footer">        
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>        
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>           </div>    
</div>  
</div>
</div>
 </td>
 </div>
```