# Bootstrap popup model not working on my webpage

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

The bootstrap popup is not showing up on my website. I have copied the popup code from the official Bootstrap website. 
Here is the link to my website [Link to webiste](http://home.india-market.online/)

The popup button is located before the footer credits.[image]

Comment: The provided url is not working. Are you loading the required bootstrap JavaScript ?

Comment: Ohh. Sorry about that, I have corrected the URL.

Comment: your modal is getting displayed but it is appearing behind the `backdrop` of the modal as you have placed the model inside an parent element (`footer`) which is having the position as `fixed` which is causing the issue of modal being displayed behind the `backdrop` for more info [Bootstrap modal appearing under background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11788713/2417602) and please share the relevant code here instead of an image so, people can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current condition :

- Query Bootstrap Modal is not working
- Below code is copy pasted from your give url http://home.india-market.online/
- It is working properly in separate example

> Solution:
>
> - You have footer, `<footer class="footer-social-icon text-center section_padding_70 clearfix">`
> - Some how there is `z-index:-101;` and `position:fixed;` in `<footer>`
> - You need to remove model outside from `<footer>` and apply directly before `</body>` tag ends.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope it will start working normally.

Old Code from website is :
[image]

Comment: Thats not copy paste. Element nesting is different thus it will work.

Comment: @ITMan, I have applied screen shot from given website, and its 100% copy from original code, which is working in above! And I also told to move it outside from `<footer>`

Comment: i mean that this is partial copy -> you have copied modal content but not exact (or meaningful) html structure. Anyway that is not important any more :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that modal content is placed (nested) inside footer element. Move that modal div to body and modal will appear.