# Bootstrap 4 modal in Angular 6 child component

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

While working with Angular 6 + Bootstrap 4 combination I stumbled upon the issue with modal. Whenever I open a modal - it opens up behind the ***modal-backdrop***. Interesting that it is not the only modal on the project, but only this one acts funny.

I have imported relevant libraries as follows (*Angular.json* file):

```
"styles": [            
          "src/styles.scss",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",  
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js", 
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

Button to open modal:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalID">Click Here</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Modal itself (simplified):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalID">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <!-- Header Here -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Body here -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-6">
          <!-- Buttons here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now all of the HTML code is inside a child component - which is a part of a parent. Code below:

```
<div class="row">    
  <div class="col-lg-9">
     <div class="space-bottom">
       <app-given-component></app-given-component>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I personally believe that the issue the modal is behind the backdrop is due to styling on *row* class. Using *dev tools* I remove the *display:flex;* and modal appears to be OK, but the rest of the styling on the page becomes messed up. I don't know how to overcome this.

Additional note: it is not an option to remove *row* or *col-lg-9* classes.

I would really appreciate your help.

Many thanks,
Alex

Comment: There are a few ways to solve this. Ideally you would put your modal directly inside <body>. If that is not an option, you could use a high z-index on the modal to force it on the foreground. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background

Comment: I cannot put it outside the component, because I'm calling some of the private functions in _.ts_ file.. Putting z-index on a modal doesn't make a change, while putting a _z-index:-1;_ on a **modal-backdrop** pushed forward not only the modal but some of the _Cards_ (which are on the same page)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple attempts to resolve the issue using *CSS* failed, I went for last resort option and combined both child and parent components. This gave me a chance to put my *modal* outside the *row* -> *col* class structure.

Apparently, you cannot use modal when one of the parent elements is *display:flex;*

Not a very nice solution, but sure does work!

Answer (score 0):

```
//angular.json
```

inside scripts

```
"./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",

"./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"

"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
```

inside style.css

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
```