# Call a Bootstrap modal 4

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I have this problem when I call the Bootstrap modal. Could someone help me or guide me how it should be?

Screenshot:

[image: Modal]

Code:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

> If the modal container has a fixed or relative position or is within
>   an element with fixed or relative position this behavior will occur.
>
> Make sure the modal container and all of its parent elements are
>   positioned the default way to fix the problem.
>
> Here are a couple ways to do this:
>
> Easiest way is to just move the modal div so it is outside any
>   elements with special positioning. One good place might be just before
>   the closing body tag .
>
> Alternatively, you can remove position:
>   CSS properties from the modal and its ancestors until the problem goes
>   away. This might change how the page looks and functions, however.

[Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background/27124430)