# Django: Bootstrap 3 modal darkens when being clicked

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-bootstrap3

This is a quiz app where several quiz can be added to a particular topic. However, when I click on the button to start the quiz, the modal asking for confirmation pops up but in a darkened way. It does not allow me to select any of the option.

What is the issue here?

Comment: A snapshot would help in a great way.

Comment: Your modal backdrop is hijacking your actual Modal popup content.

Comment: An old answer, but you'll get the point : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background

Comment: @MukulKapoor, thanks but I've tried, it aint working. Actually, I noticed something. I have an {% include 'footer.html' %}. If I remove it, everything goes fine. However, if i put it after the footer, still it does not work. :(

Comment: Try placing your Modal code outside of your main content. Place it just before the closing Body tag.

Comment: @MukulKapoor, still not working

Comment: Bootstrap adds a Div with class modal-backdrop just before the closing body tag (after you open the modal). Try fiddling with its z-index value to see if we are debugging it right.