# Modal Backdrop block the modal content on portrait screen orientation in laravel blade

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

Hi in my laravel blade I have a modal opening up when the screen orientation is Portrait with a message saying rotate the screen to landscape mode.

But Every time when I check this with iPad pro portrait mode, even though the modal pops up, it's blocked with the backdrop div

[image]

The modal works fine on same device but the landscape mode...

Following is the modal code

```
<div id="oMsg" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <!-- device orientation modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">{{ __('Attention') }}</h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body info">
                                        <p class="roleChange_popupText">
                                            Veuillez faire pivoter votre appareil en mode paysage.
                                        </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer mb-4">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 text-right mb-4">
                                        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-admin-form-save">{{ __('Confirmer') }}</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

How can I take the modal to the front and enable the button on portrait mode?

Comment: Yo should include the CSS code related to your issue/question

Comment: I have not touched my bootstrap css elated to the modal,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use your modal code just before the ending `body` tag.

For more details you may refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background)

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your situation without the rest of the HTML code but perhaps this might be a `z-index` and positioning issue. Try the following

Since you don't have a CSS document, apply `z-index: 999;` to your modal div using inline style. Be sure to also include an appropriate `position` rule. Why? In order to bring your modal above other elements, you must assign a position rule other than the default.

Here's an example:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" style="z-index: 999; position: relative;">
```