# Modal Inside NavBar Not Opening

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm using Vue and Bootstrap 4 to create a NavBar that has a modal child component. That modal is in a menu dropdown. When I click on the modal, the screen fades but I can't see the modal. [This is what it looks like](https://imgur.com/a/kUUy4O4)

I know this issue has been asked a lot years ago ([like this one from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background)). I've tried changing the z-index, removing the background fade and color as well as the fixed-top nav but those haven't worked. Any help on this would be appreciated!

**NavBar:**

```
<div class="app">  
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-info">
    
      <!-- Collapse Toggle -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    
      <!-- Actions & Info -->
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">         
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <span class="nav-bar-media-text-size">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Actions & Info
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item">
                  <AddRecipe />
                </a>             
              </div>
            </span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>      
    </nav>
</div>
```

**Modal Component:**

```
  <div>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addCocktailModal">
      Add Cocktail
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="addCocktailModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="addCocktailModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="addCocktailModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
<script>
  import AddRecipe from '../components/AddRecipe.vue';

  export default {
    components: {
      AddRecipe,
    },
</script>
```

I moved the modal outside the dropdown. The modal was [finally visible](https://imgur.com/a/Yj4xucl) but I couldn't interact with it.

The modal works fine outside the NavBar but I want it to be in the NavBar in the dropdown menu.

Comment: This would be much easier to debug if you presented rendered HTML instead of Vue markup. You could also create and link to a Vue app demo if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the button that opens the modal inside the navbar without having the modal itself inside the navbar.

Split your Modal Component into 2 components: one that delivers the button, the other that delivers the modal.

Put the button inside the navbar, and the modal outside!